# get numbers from string and use them to create an object javascript

Tags: javascript

So I would have the next string:

```
const string = "1,22, 28,40,4, 8,24,31,33"

var config = {
        config_key: config_key,
        location_key: null,
        autoassign: 1,
                    }
```

I would need to create 9 objects from this string where the `location_key:` is equal with a value in the string, the other object prop. remains the same.

Comment: Have you tried anything that isn't exactly working how you want? If so, please add it to your question

Comment: Also, should the numbers from the string remain as strings or should they be interpreted as numbers?

Comment: I've played around with it, trying to convert it to array first and then trying to create the objects ... but my head is spinning around when it comes to array and objects, and moving data from one to another. Just start to learn.

Comment: You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61198098/edit) to show those attempts. Also, about those strings vs numbers.... ?

Comment: no they don't have to be numbers, seems that squlize is inserting them into the database correctly. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string on `/, ?/` (comma and optional space) then map those values to new objects, using `config` as a template and override the `location_key` using the string value.

```js
const string = "1,22, 28,40,4, 8,24,31,33"

const config = {
  config_key: 'config_key',
  location_key: null,
  autoassign: 1,
}

const parsed = string.split(/, ?/).map(location_key => ({
  ...config,
  location_key
}))

console.info(parsed)
```

---

Since your question states...

> where the `location_key:` is equal with a value in the string

I assumed you wanted to keep the values from the string as strings but if you want them treated as actual numbers (integers), use

```js
location_key: parseInt(location_key, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a constructor to create each `new` instance of an Object:

```js
const string = "1,22, 28,40,4, 8,24,31,33", config_key = 'testing';
function Config(locationKey){
  this.config_key = config_key;
  this.location_key = +locationKey;
  this.autoassign = 1;
}
const nums = string.split(/\s*,\s*/), objs = [];
nums.forEach(n=>{
  objs.push(new Config(n));
});
console.log(objs);
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer, the ES6 method seems more simple but yours is nice too.

Comment: You did notice those location_keys are numbers in my example. And that is ES6. Notice the arrow function. I prefer constructors to classes, for a number of reasons you've yet to understand.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed, I don't really need them numbers but it is a good example to save and have for the future. Thanks again for taking the time.